# Prefer quoting vs. escaping for ZSH completion

Tags: shell, zsh, quoting

ZSH is a wonderful shell, and all of the excellent auto-complete scripts written for it make it a breeze to learn and use.

However, I dislike that the autocompletions will use `foo\ bar` instead of `'foo bar'`.

Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: Why do you prefer zsh to modify something which you have already typed on the command line? This would not be what I would intuitively consider as "completion". And, why does the backslash hurt you?

Comment: ZLE can totally modify what's already typed on the command line, and quoting is more pleasing on the eye than escaping, so this is an understandable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More of a comment, but need better formatting, so here goes.

I believe this should be possible in ZLE, but I don't know if there's code already available for this purpose, and it's been a while since I last programmed lower-level ZLE so I don't have time to freshen up and code it up myself...

However, this is sort of possible in using stock functions already. I'm talking about [`quote-and-complete-word`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Functions/Zle/quote-and-complete-word):

```
# This widget uses the completion system to double-quote the current word
# if it is not already quoted, then attempts to complete normally.  If the
# normal completion fails, the quotes are removed again.
#
# To use it:
#   autoload -Uz quote-and-complete-word
#   zle -N quote-and-complete-word
#   bindkey '\t' quote-and-complete-word
```

Since it unconditionally quotes the word, it's obviously a bad idea to bind tab to it, but you may bind something else, say alt tab:

```
autoload -Uz quote-and-complete-word
zle -N quote-and-complete-word
bindkey '^[^I' quote-and-complete-word
```

(Or `^[[Z` for shift tab.)

When you need to complete to something quoted, you press alt tab. Note that after completion, the cursor will be inside the quotes and you need to move one character right to leave the quotes behind, so it's unfortunately not ideal even as a variant.

Comment: Is there a variant of `quote-and-complete-word` which does not quote things which do not require quoting?